# How do I reformat MAC addresses using sed?

Tags: mac-address

I have a MAC address which is in the standard `:`-separated format, such as  08:f1:ea:6d:03:3c, that I would like to print out as three sets of four hexadecimal digits separated by a `.`, such as 08f1.ea6d.033c

I tried `echo 08:f1:ea:6d:03:3c | sed 's/://g'`, but that produces: 08f1ea6d033c.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take what you've got, and add `'s/.\{4\}/&./g;s/.$//'` to the `sed` expression. All together, that's:

```
echo 08:f1:ea:6d:03:3c | sed 's/://g;s/.\{4\}/&./g;s/.$//'
```

As you've noted, your `sed` expression removes all `:`s; the `;s/.\{4\}/&./g` adds a `.` after every four digits, and the `;s/.$//'` removes the trailing `.` added by the previous expression.